# transactions costs and leland modified volatility

Tags: delta-hedging, transaction-costs

When there are transactions costs, we are in a situation of incomplete market. What does the modified volatility of Leland (*Option Pricing and Replication with Transactions Costs*, 1985) bring us? can we replicate the option when computing/hedging the risks with this volatility?

Comment: Once you select a hedging frequency, dynamic hedging at that frequency using the Leland modified vol is certainly a *feasible* strategy, but it is not necessarily *optimal*. (In particular as $\Delta t$ becomes small it is probably *not* an optimal strategy, and not in continuous time limit). Still, it provides a useful estimate of option value in practical cases, where hedging is discrete time (and assuming you are selling and then hedging the option).

Comment: thank you. can we replicate the option if we hedge using the leland modified volatility and if the transaction costs are constant?

Comment: Perfect replication no, you will replicate with a (random) hedging error